# SQL search query with dynamically build where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, where-clause

```
Table Orders
| id |
|----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |

Table Items
| id |
|----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |


Table OrderItems
| order_id | item_id |
|---------------------|
| 1        | 1        |
| 1        | 2        |
| 1        | 3        |
|---------------------|
| 2        | 1        |
| 2        | 4        |
| 2        | 5        |
|---------------------|
| 3        | 1        |
| 3        | 2        |
| 3        | 4        |
| 3        | 5        |
```

So the user is able to build a dynamic query in the frontend with operators `AND` `OR` and comparison `EQUAL( = )`, `NOT EQUAL( != )`. He also has the ability to create conditional groups with parentheses.

Based on these requirements I'll create dynamic expressions in the `WHERE` part.
Example: User wants to have all orders which have the item 1 and either item 2 or 3 and NOT item 4
expression build:

`item_id = 1 AND (item_id = 2 OR item_id = 3) AND item_id != 4`

Based on this expression only **Order 1** should be selected.
My solution would be to `JOIN` the table **OrderItems** on the `order_id` as often as `AND` operators exist to get to the result:

```
SELECT o.id 
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi1 ON o.id         = oi1.order_id
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi2 ON oi1.order_id = oi2.order_id
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi3 ON oi2.order_id = oi3.order_id
WHERE o1.item_id = 1 AND (oi2.item_id = 2 OR oi2.item_id = 3) AND oi3.item_id != 4
GROUP BY o.id
```

Is there a more elegant solution? There might be a problem if there are more complex queries which will have more and more joins ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses aggregation:

```
SELECT o.id 
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE oi.item_id = 1) > 0
    AND COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE oi.item_id IN (2, 3) > 0
    AND COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE oi.item_id = 4) = 0
```

It is realtively easy to programmatically generate the `HAVING` clause with more conditional counts.

You can make the query a bit more efficient by adding a `WHERE` clause to pre-filter on the `item_id`s that you are interested in:

```
SELECT o.id 
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
WHERE oi.item_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE oi.item_id = 1) > 0
    AND COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE oi.item_id IN (2, 3) > 0
    AND COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE oi.item_id = 4) = 0
```

Comment: I would use `COUNT(DISTINCT oi.item_id)` to cover orders that include the same item multiple times. Apart from that it looks good to me.

Comment: @TheImpaler: thanks. Actually I think `> 0` has this covered.

Answer (score 0):

thx @GMB based on your approach with aggregation I came up with this:

```
SELECT oi1.order_id
FROM (
    SELECT oi.order_id, array_agg(oi.item_id) AS arr_item
    FROM OrderItems oi
    WHERE oi.item_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    GROUP BY oi.order_id
) AS oi1
WHERE 1 = ANY(oi1.arr_item) AND (2 = ANY(oi1.arr_item) OR 3 = ANY(oi1.arr_item)) AND 4 != ALL(oi1.arr_item);
```

Based on `EXPLAIN` there is one less step in the `HAVING` solution because there is no Subquery Scan needed. Which I think would be faster in the long run